# C:\Users\2019b>show dbs. 'show' is not recognized as an internal or external command, . how to fix this, im using version": "6.0.8" of mongo db

Tags: mongodb

show dbs command is not working on mongo DB latest version

i was expecting output[this image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iF5V.jpg)
it should show the list of database
C:\Users\2019b>show dbs. 'show' is not recognized as an internal or external command, . how to fix this, im using version": "6.0.8" of mongo db

Comment: `show dbs` is a Mongo shell command, not a stand-alone program. First you must start the mongo shell and connect to a database.